# Wrapping unittest TestCases in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

Hi I'm trying to tweak Python's standard unittest library to my own needs.
So far everything is experimental and I want to know if I'm doing something wrong, so here is my code:

```
class Should(object):
    def __init__(self, subject):
        self.subject = subject
        self.suite = unittest.TestSuite()

    def run(self):
        unittest.TextTestResult().run(self.suite)

    def contain(self, elem):
        subject = self.subject
        class Contain(unittest.TestCase):
            def test_contain(self):
                self.assertIn(elem, subject)
        self.suite.addTest(Contain('test_contain'))

should = Should([1, 2, 3])
should.contain(1)
should.run()
```

If I run this piece of code I get the following error:

```
unittest.TextTestResult().run(self.suite)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)
```

According to what I've read from the unittest documentation the line `unittest.TextTestResult().run(self.suite)` should run the test cases on the suite.

Am I doing something wrong or it's just that the way I'm wrapping the test cases is not viable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt with Python, check the standard library source.

```
class TextTestResult(result.TestResult):
    """A test result class that can print formatted text results to a stream.

    Used by TextTestRunner.
    """
    separator1 = '=' * 70
    separator2 = '-' * 70

    def __init__(self, stream, descriptions, verbosity):
        super(TextTestResult, self).__init__()
        self.stream = stream
        self.showAll = verbosity > 1
        self.dots = verbosity == 1
        self.descriptions = descriptions
```

So the missing parameters are `descriptions` and `verbosity`. The first is a boolean to turn on or off long descriptions of the tests, the second adjusts verbosity.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Should(object):
    def __init__(self, *subject):
        self.subject = subject
        self.suite = unittest.TestSuite()

    def run(self):
        unittest.TextTestResult().run(self.suite)

    def contain(self, elem):
        subject = self.subject
        class Contain(unittest.TestCase):
            def test_contain(self):
                self.assertIn(elem, subject)
        self.suite.addTest(Contain('test_contain'))

should = Should([1, 2, 3])
should.contain(1)
should.run()
```

Use ***subject**, You will not get error now.